# Regex - optional text followed by greedily matched repeating text

Tags: python, regex

**Please help me fix my regex :).**

Summary: How can I make a repeating group (tags) match greedily even if it means a preceding optional group (a label) is empty.

For some reason, my regex is not acting as desired:

```
code:     re.match("^foo(-.*?)?((?:-(?:a|b))*)$", "foo-a-b").groups()
output:   ('-a', '-b')
expected: ('', '-a-b') # since "-a" and "-b" are both tags that should be greedily matched by the last pattern
```

Examples of expected behavior:

| Input | Expected | Current Output | Notes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| foo-a-b | ('', '-a-b') | ('-a', '-b') | everything after "foo" is a tag, so label should be empty |
| foo-b-a | ('', '-b-a') | ('-b', '-a') | everything after "foo" is a tag, so label should be empty |
| foo-c-a-b | ('-c', '-a-b') | as expected | has both a label and a tag |
| foo-a-b-c | ('-a-b-c', '') | as expected | everything is a label because tags can only be at the end |

My real-life problem has a much more complicated definition of tags, labels, and "foo", but the issue is reproducible even with this smaller contrived example.

Ideally, I'd also prefer to avoid having to repeat the "a|b" part of the regex, since in my real system it is actually a really long and complex pattern. If repeating that part of the regex is unavoidable, that's okay though! Repeating it within a negative look-behind also throws an error because of variable-length strings:

```
r_tags_nonames = re.sub("\(\?P<.+?>", "(?:", r_tags)
re.match(r_tags, example).groups()
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "foo.py", line 210, in <module>
    _main()
  File "foo.py", line 119, in _main
    format, match = firstMatch(fileRoot)
  File "foo.py", line 90, in firstMatch
    match = re.fullmatch(regex, path, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
  ...
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/sre_compile.py", line 182, in _compile
    raise error("look-behind requires fixed-width pattern")
re.error: look-behind requires fixed-width pattern
```

An example of a more complex version of this where repeating is problematic (because of renaming) – imagine dozens of such tags where the tags themselves also have subtags with names and their own regexes:

```
"^foo(-.*?)?((?:-(?:(?P<tag1>hello)|(?P<tag2>world)))*)$"
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What tool/language do you use?

Comment: @PoulBak Python (the re module)

Answer (score 2):

You can add a negative lookbehind after the `label` group to assert that it didn't finish with a tag (`a` or `b`), this will force all tags to be matched by the `tags` group.

```regex
foo(-.*?)?(?<!a|b)((?:-(?:a|b))*)$
```

In python:

```py
import re

strs = [
        'foo-a-b',
        'foo-b-a',
        'foo-c-a-b',
        'foo-a-b-c'
        ]

for s in strs:
    res = re.match("foo(-.*?)?(?<!a|b)((?:-(?:a|b))*)$", s).groups()
    print(res)
```

Output:

```py
(None, '-a-b')
(None, '-b-a')
('-c', '-a-b')
('-a-b-c', '')
```

If you can use the `regex` module instead of `re`, you can use the `(?r)` flag to search backwards and avoid the lookbehind:

```py
import regex

strs = [
        'foo-a-b',
        'foo-b-a',
        'foo-c-a-b',
        'foo-a-b-c'
        ]

for s in strs:
    res = regex.match('(?r)foo(-.*?)?((?:-(?:a|b))*)$', s).groups()
    print(res)
```

Output:

```py
(None, '-a-b')
(None, '-b-a')
('-c', '-a-b')
('-a-b-c', '')
```

Comment: If "(a|b)" is actually a very complex and long regex (I shortened it for the StackOverflow example), is there any way to avoid repeating the pattern in the regex for the look-behind?

Comment: @MatthewStrax-Haber sorry about the lack of reply, been night time here. Unfortunately the lookbehind (like the lookahead in the other answer) needs to repeat the regex. I did think of one way to work around this by processing the string backwards, but that requires reversing the `a` and `b` regexes as well. See for example https://rextester.com/UIV11477

Comment: @MatthewStrax-Haber I've added a solution to my answer using the `regex` module `(?r)` flag which searches the string backwards. This avoids the need for the lookbehind.

Comment: @MatthewStrax-Haber in the regex example you gave [here](https://regex101.com/r/ZuUUoF/2) is that as complex as the tags are?

Comment: Thanks! We now have a solution with the PyPi regex module and reverse, but that doesn't work well as 1) I don't want a dependency, and 2) the system loops through a bunch of regex's, and others break if I reverse the strings. This is an example on regex101 if it makes it easier to play around with: regex101.com/r/ZuUUoF/2 . I also added an updated example of how look-behind isn't working because the tag patterns aren't all the same length.

Comment: @MatthewStrax-Haber I'm glad you have something working. I don't think standard python re can solve this problem unless labels can't include the character that separates them from the tags (`-` in your question, `_` on the demo) e.g. https://regex101.com/r/gKhXW8/1

Comment: unfortunately, the separators are the same for both words in labels and tags (it can actually be anything that matches "[_-\. ]"). If it's not possible, I will add a boolean value to the data structure that holds all of the regexes that determines if it should be run in reverse. It's not ideal and quite hacky, but it'll work until I run into a regex where this problem happens in both directions. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @MatthewStrax-Haber I'll keep thinking about it. I'm glad you've got something that's workable at present.

Comment: Thanks! Let me know if you think of something. It's a fun puzzle :)

Answer (score 2):

You might also you a negative lookahead to grab as much as possible in group 1 as long as there are not only `-a` or `-b` parts left until the end of the string.

```
^foo((?:(?!(?:-[ab])*$)-[^\s-]+)*)((?:-[ab])*)$
```

- `^foo` Start of string, match `foo`
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `(?:` Non capture group

    - `(?!(?:-(?:a|b))*$)` Assert not only `-a` or `-b` parts till the end of string
    - `-[^\s-]+` Match `-` followed by 1+ non whitespace chars other than `-`
  - `)*` Close group and optionally repeat it
- `)` Close group 1
- `(` Capture **group 2**

  - `(?:-(?:a|b))*` Optionally repeat `-a` or `-b`
- `)` Close group 2
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FDrIfw/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/7D65NF)

If the values can literally be only a or b, you could also use a character class `[ab]`

```
^foo((?:(?!(?:-[ab])*$)-[^\s-]+)*)((?:-[ab])*)$
```

Example

```
import re

strings = ['foo-a-b', 'foo-b-a', 'foo-c-a-b', 'foo-a-b-c']

for s in strings:
    print(re.match("^foo((?:(?!(?:-(?:a|b))*$)-[^\s-]+)*)((?:-(?:a|b))*)$", s).groups())
```

Output

```
('', '-a-b')
('', '-b-a')
('-c', '-a-b')
('-a-b-c', '')
```

Comment: If "(a|b)" is actually a very complex and long regex (I shortened it for the StackOverflow example), is there any way to avoid repeating the pattern in the regex for the look-behind?

Comment: @Matthew  Can you update the question with an example?

Comment: @Fourth Bird: I just added it. I also realized while implementing your code that it is problematic because I get this error:

```re.error: redefinition of group name 'year' as group 40; was group 5 at position 1869```

Comment: Seems like you are reusing the named capture group. Can you use it only once with the name?

Comment: I was only using each name once until I tried to add "(?<!a|b)" before "((?:a|b)*)", where a="(?P<year>foo)" and b="(?P<blah>bar)". Is there a way around having to have two versions of the patterns, with one having names and one without? For example, is there a way to refer to the third capturing group in the negative look-behind rather than repeat its definition?

Comment: @Matthew Do you have a regex101 link with the real pattern? Does it have to be re or can it also be the regex module?

Comment: @bird I'd much prefer it be in re, as regex requires a library be installed to work. This is an example on regex101 if it makes it easier to play around with: https://regex101.com/r/ZuUUoF/2